# Error occurred during initialization of VM,error in opening files

Tags: java, jvm

Some time back it was working fine on command prompt but I don't know why it is showing errors now. I have tried setting the java path still error persists. Also checked the files msvcr100.dll and rt.jar both are present and are not empty. Please help if u can :)

[image: this is the error]
[image: this is the path]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall JDK. Path seemingly works fine there

Answer (score 0):

After trying a number of solutions, at last I used the java update installer it upgraded the java version and the problem was solved.